# Displaying JavaScript function result in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner trying to display my JavaScript calculated results in my webpage but did not work. Please see my javaScript and HTML files below and advise me on what is wrong.

```
function fedTaxCalc(){  
  function estimateTax(){
  let grossPay = document.getElementById('grossPay').value;
 if (grossPay > 250 && grossPay <= 500){return 250*0.50;}
    else {return 'Invalid no';}
   }
console.log(estimateTax());
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = estimateTax();
    }
  


<form>
  <input id="grossPay" type="number" placeholder = "grossPymt">
  <input type = "button" onclick = "fedTaxCalc()" value = "Submit">
</form>
<div>Result: <input type = "number" id="result"> </div>
```

Comment: `input` element can't contain HTML, set its `value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find three mistakes

1. your JavaScript function should be wrapped in <script> label
2. change result type to text to accept "Invalid no"
3. change innerHTML to value

```html
<script>
    function fedTaxCalc() {
        function estimateTax() {
            let grossPay = document.getElementById('grossPay').value;
            if (grossPay > 250 && grossPay <= 500) { return 250 * 0.50; }
            else { return 'Invalid no'; }
        }
        console.log(estimateTax());
        document.getElementById("result").value = estimateTax();
    }
</script>


<form>
    <input id="grossPay" type="number" placeholder="grossPymt">
    <input type="button" onclick="fedTaxCalc()" value="Submit">
</form>
<div>Result: <input type="text" id="result"> </div>
```

PS:
use a text edit to format your code. vscode is a good choice!

Comment: So grateful to JumHorn. This works perfectly.